# recordViewForm not pre-populating input fields for certain profiles in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, profile, field-level-security, fls, lightning-recordviewform

I have an aura component with a recordViewForm that displays multiple fields from the Account object . These input fields are supposed to be pre-populated but are not displaying for a certain profile but working just fine for Admin profile.

I double checked that the profile has read and create access to Account object and a lookup field , and double checked the fls on the displayed fields.

My controller is without sharing .
Any help ?

Comment: Hi there, just to clarify, the profile that is causing the issue has read access to the fields that aren't displaying? Also if it's possible, it's useful to include your code in your question to help us help you.

Comment: Hi, yes. The profile has read access to those fields , in fact he has almost the exact same access as the Admin profile.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! Make sure the apex controller class used is accessible to your profile ! I had completely forgotten to check that detail and it cost me two days on investigating.